# Javascript Countdown Date

Tags: javascript, countdown, countdowntimer

probably an easy question for many of you. :)

I'm trying to use the simple counter from this countdown: https://github.com/rendro/countdown and i'm stuck passing javascript variable.

Normally the end date format for this counter is:

```
var endDate = "June 7, 2087 15:03:25";
```

then in the function you pass the variable:

```
$('.countdown.simple').countdown({ date: endDate });
```

but i'm trying to get a dynamic 24h date and time and sending the output in the same original endDate format. The goal is to have a countdown purchased timer to purchase this product before the end of the day so (time now - and of the day). Unfortunately its not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dateNow = new Date();
    var monthsArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var monthNow = monthsArray[dateNow.getMonth()];
    var dayNow = dateNow.getDate();
    var yearNow = dateNow.getFullYear();
    var hourNow = dateNow.getHours();
    var minNow = dateNow.getMinutes();
    var secNow = dateNow.getSeconds();
    var completeDate = monthNow + " " + dayNow + ", " + yearNow + " " + hourNow + ":" + minNow + ":" + secNow;

  $(function() {
    $('.countdown.simple').countdown({ date: completeDate });
  });

    alert(completeDate);
</script>
```

i have set an alert to test the output format and its working well. But my counter is showing 0 years, 0 days, 00 hours, 00 min and 00 sec.

whats wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the end date for the countdown timer to the present date. You need to pass in a future date.

Instead of creating a date string, you can also just pass in a date object.

**Example**

```
// Create the date object
var completeDate = new Date();

// Set the date to the last possible second of the day
completeDate.setHours(23, 59, 59);

// Start the timer
$(function() {
    $('.countdown.simple').countdown({ date: completeDate });
});
```

Comment: Oh.. I see.. A lot more simple hehehe

Got it, thank you I learned.